# Can't create table with ForeignCollection of same type

Tags: android, dao, ormlite

I need to implement subchapters and tried following approach:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "chapters")
public class Chapter  implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3500051084584514827L;

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int _id;


    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    private String name;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true)
    private Project project;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true, maxEagerForeignCollectionLevel = 2)
    public ForeignCollection<Document> documents;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    public ForeignCollection<Chapter> subChapters;

    public int getId() {
        return _id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }


    Chapter() {
    }

    public Chapter(String name, Project project) {
        this.name = name;
        this.project = project;
    }
}
```

But it throws me an exception:

> Can't create database
>                                                                                                    java.sql.SQLException: Foreign collection class ....models.db.Chapter for field 'subChapters' column-name does not contain a foreign field of class ...models.db.Chapter

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I missed to add the foreign object:

```
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = true, foreign = true)
private Chapter parent;
```